# Confusing grammatical numbers

Tags: riddle, word, lateral-thinking, rhyme

What am I?

> At StackExchange science I become:
>   
> Plural at a pyramid bottom
>   
> Our four letters may lead to wisdom
>   
> Singular with five to locate from
>   
> In New Zealand a peak is my home.

This has been through the [sandbox](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5276/the-riddle-sandbox).

Hint 1:

> Verses group as follow: 2 and 3 go together, and 4 and 5 as well.

Hint 2:

> Seldom, words were chosen for the rhyme. You can read "a peak is my home" as "a peak is my own".

Comment: The last line makes me think COOK, but it doesn't fit with the rest.

Comment: It fits a couple of definitions but it is not related

Comment: 'Our four letters may lead to wisdom' it means, word has more than four letters right?

Comment: also, does first line represents http://stackexchange.com/sites#science-traffic

Comment: 'Our four letters may lead to wisdom' it means, word has more than four letters right?' Both "yes" and "no", there is a dual interpretation.

Comment: @smriti No,  the relationship with StackExchange is closer

Comment: should we remove the (ex)-sandbox reference?

Comment: @Jon Mark Perry I do not know, I am still puzzled by the negative reactions to my related OP at meta http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/5366/25964

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got it! The answer is

> DATUM / DATA.

The title refers to the fact that

> the singular and plural forms of this word (changing the number) don't reflect standard English grammar, which may be confusing to some.

*At StackExchange science I become:*

> [Data Science Stack Exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/), currently still in beta and not a fully-fledged graduate site.

*Plural at a pyramid bottom

Our four letters may lead to wisdom*

> DATA (the 4-letter plural form) is at the bottom of the [DIKW pyramid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIKW_Pyramid), also known as the Wisdom Hierarchy:
>
>  [image: pyramid]

*Singular with five to locate from

In New Zealand a peak is my home.*

> DATUM (the 5-letter singular form) can be found in [geodesic datum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodetic_datum), a system for locating points on the Earth, and also [Datum Peak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datum_Peak) in New Zealand.

---

**Feedback section**

It's a nice riddle, and the clues all fit together in a clear and obvious way once you find the answer (all the best riddles have self-justifying solutions). However, the solution is quite difficult to come up with, and the clues don't all feel completely 'natural' (e.g. did you really know about that peak in New Zealand before you came across it as a way of cluing in the singular form?)

Comment: As a [scifi.se] mod, I must express my disappointment that you didn't include a Star Trek reference in this riddle.

Comment: @LaurentDuval Added in a bit about geodesic datum, and the title (which I had understood, but forgot to include originally).

Comment: @LaurentDuval "Data is" is wrong; "data are" is correct. Data is always the plural form of datum. Will edit in the bit about "become".

Comment: As a mass noun, with the limits of my knowledge, I am not as affirmative "This is well established and generally accepted in standard English writing: 
Data was collected over a number of years."
http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2014/04/data-media-two-tricky-latin-plurals-handle/ (only one of many examples and discussions). Conclusion of the above "Data can take either a singular or plural verb in standard English, but be consistent within a piece of writing, always check the style policy of your organization, and make yourself familiar with the grammatical debate that exists around them."

Comment: @LaurentDuval Since they decided that ["literally" could mean "not literally"](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/literally), I don't trust the Oxford Dictionary any more.

Comment: @LaurentDuval No, but being wrong is on their record, and they also happen to be wrong about "data" being able to be singular. (I'm a grammar pedant, sorry :-) I even boast about it on my user profile!)

Comment: First answer post suspension. Well done, rand! Welcome back!

Comment: @CodeNewbie Thanks! :-D I waited to post an answer until I found one I was 100% sure I'd got right - it would be so anticlimactic to wait a year and then get something wrong! Here's my first puzzle post-suspension: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41859/a-moderate-visual-number-puzzle

Answer (score 10):

Potentially:

> Kiwi (bird)

Explanation:

At StackExchange science I become: 
Plural at a pyramid bottom

> The kiwi resides at the bottom of the food pyramid and Kiwi is plural (or singular as used later)

Our four letters may lead to wisdom

> Kiwi rearranges to wiki; where I gather all my knowledge

Singular with five to locate from

> Appropriately Wikipedia has told me there are 5 species of Kiwi and a single Kiwi (bird) can 'locate' from these five species

In New Zealand a peak is my home.

> Kiwi live in New Zealand!

Comment: Not very convincing IMO. No connection with science on Stack Exchange, or with peaks in New Zealand.

Comment: @randal'thor The science on Stack Exchange I was thinking pointed to the food chain pyramid idea. The peak bit was where I felt it was weakest too. It just seems to fit so well with the middle two clues I feel like it must be right and I am missing some vital knowledge about kiwi...

Comment: @Teddysted it's... not a bird. Yet very original and elaborate answer (the wiki anagram). I do not know where kiwi(s) dwell, so the peak connection is not here. The part "science on Stack Exchange" is more specific.

Comment: @LauretDuval That's a pity; it all seemed to fit so well! Will continue thinking

Answer (score 2):

You might be

> Data

Because:

At StackExchange science I become:

> There is a data science page on StackExchange

Plural at a pyramid bottom

> At the bottom of the DIKW Pyramid is data, data is plural

Our four letters may lead to wisdom

> If you have a lot of data, you could be considered wise and data has four letters

Singular with five to locate from

> With 5 gps satelites data your location can be calculated (not sure)

In New Zealand a peak is my home:

> I've got no clue about this one

Comment: The initial point is quite interesting. Could you further elaborate?

Comment: @LaurentDuval, you mean about the science part? what would you like me to elaborate, I think it's pretty clear?

Comment: I would say that you are almost halfway from the answer. Several bits of information have not been used yet: for instance the two last verses, the title, and a couple of others. I have understood that a full answer and a thorough explanation are quality indicators

Comment: I've edited my answer, even though I'm still not sure about the last one sadly